# Docker: mount image's original /docker-entrypoint.sh to a volume in read/write mode

Tags: linux, docker

I try to mount image's original `/docker-entrypoint.sh` to a volume in read/write mode, in order to be able to change it easily from outside (without entering the container) and then restart the container to observe the changes.

I do it (in ansible) like this:

`/app/docker-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint.sh:rw`

If `/app/docker-entrypoint.sh` doesn't exist on the host, a directory `/app/docker-entrypoint.sh` (not a file, as wish) is created, and I get following error:

```
Error starting container e40a90eef1525f554e6078e20b3ab5d1c4b27ad2a7d73aa3bf4f7c6aa337be4f: 400 Client Error: Bad Request (\"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:402: container init caused \\\"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\\\\\"/app/docker-entrypoint.sh\\\\\\\" to rootfs \\\\\\\"/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/4d3e4f4082ca621ab5f3a4ec3f810b967634b1703fd71ec00b4860c59494659a/rootfs\\\\\\\" at \\\\\\\"/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/4d3e4f4082ca621ab5f3a4ec3f810b967634b1703fd71ec00b4860c59494659a/rootfs/docker-entrypoint.sh\\\\\\\" caused \\\\\\\"not a directory\\\\\\\"\\\"\": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

If I touch `/app/docker-entrypoint.sh` (and set proper permissions) before launching the container - the container fails to start up and keeps restarting (I assume because the `/app/docker-entrypoint.sh` and therefore internal `/docker-entrypoint.sh` are empty).

How can I mount the original content of container's `/docker-entrypoint.sh` to the outside?

Comment: Mounting single files does not work in all environments (such as from Windows hosts). Why not mount the whole `/app` into `/app` or something? You can then start the container with `/app/my-entrypoint.sh` instead.

Comment: You can also use `docker cp` to copy files between running container and host system.

Comment: What's the final state you're trying to get to?  I'd try to build a new image with the modified entrypoint script, and you'd need it in your source control system.  I guess I'm unclear why you don't already have the script, and why you're trying to use volumes to replace code.

Comment: @DavidMaze, final state: container launches and dumps the content of its /docker-entrypoint.sh onto a volume, where it can be easily manipulated without rebuilding the image. Motivation: this way you can tune(/make ad-hoc changes, like enabling debug mode) the container fast and easy by simply changing the file on the host and then restarting the container.

Comment: You should look into configuration knobs like environment variables that make this sort of thing easier to do.  If you need to tune the startup sequence of an image, check out its source tree (including its Dockerfile, entrypoint script, and other artifacts) and try to tweak it there, maybe doing iterative `docker build`/`docker run`.  I'd keep volumes out of this, and I definitely wouldn't be trying to live-edit application code in a deployment environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override docker-entry point it should be executable or in other words you have to set `chmod +x your_mount_entrypoint.sh` in the host then you can mount otherwise it will through permission error. As entrypoint script should be executable.

Second thing, As mentioned in the comment you can mount the file better to keep the entrypoint script in directory like `docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh`.

or if you want to mount specific file then both name should be same otherwise entrypoint script will not be overridden.

```
docker run --name test -v $PWD/entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh --rm my_image
```

or

```
docker run --name test -v $PWD/entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh:rw --rm my_image
```

See this example, entrypoint generated inside dockerfile and you can overide this from any script but it should be executable and should be mount to `docker-entrypoint`.
Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint
RUN echo -e $'#!/bin/sh \n\
echo "hello from docker generated entrypoint" >> /test.txt \n\
tail -f /test.txt ' >> /docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh"]
```

if you build and run it you will

```
docker build -t my_image .
docker run -t --rm my_image
#output
hello from docker generated entrypoint
```

Now if you want to overide

Create and set permission
`host_path/entrypoint/entrypoint.sh`
for example entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello from entrypoint using mounted"
```

Now run

```
docker run --name test -v $PWD/:/docker-entrypoint/ --rm  my_image
#output
hello from entrypoint using mounted
```

**Update:**

If you mount directory of the host it will hide the content of docker image.

The workaround

- Mount some directory other then entrypoint name it backup
- add instruction in entrypoint to copy entrypoint to that location at run time
- So it will create new file on the host directory instead

```
FROM alpine
RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint
RUN touch /docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh
RUN echo -e $'#!/bin/sh \n\
echo "hello from entrypoint" \n\
cp /docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh /for_hostsystem/ ' >> /docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Now if you run you will have the docker entrypoint in the host, as opposit as you want

```
docker run --name test -v $PWD/:/for_hostsystem/ --rm my_image
```

Comment: I want to achieve the opposite - overwrite the file on the host by the file from inside the container. So, once launched/mounted, I see 'hello from docker generated entrypoint'. This way I can easily tweak docker-entrypoint.sh from outside and then just restart the container.

Comment: docker will always hide container content if host volume attached to the directory.  the workaround can be to have different directory and mount that directory to write entrypoint to host voume with out hiding the container one. let me post some wrok arround.

Comment: But now if I change entrypoint.sh on the host and restart the container - it will not influence the behavior, since it's only a copy of entrypoint.sh, not the entrypoint.sh itself.

Comment: As I mentioned it not possible, you grab the entrypoint now  change it and mount it with ` $PWD/:/docker-entrypoint/` and contaier will this

Comment: Is this what you need?